# Adding list element in HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use jQuery to add a list item with the format has already been used. However, where the first element (the top one) has the right format the one below (added after pressing "Add entry") doesnt have the same format. The whole code is below but I have extracted the function creating the entry.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add entry</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    $("#myList").append('<ul  data-role="listview" data-input="#myFilter" data-inset="true"><li id="contact1"><a href="#">testContact</a></li></ul>');
}
</script>
```

The whole code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="panel" id="contactPanel"> 
            <a href="#pageone" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
        <form class="ui-filterable">
          <input id="myFilter" data-type="search">
        </form>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
          <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Albert</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cameron</a></li>
        </ul>
    
      </div> 
    
      <div data-role="panel" id="dialPanel" data-position-fixed="true"> 
       <a href="#pageone" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
        <h2>Dial a Number</h2>
        <p>You can close the panel by clicking outside the panel, pressing the Esc key, by swiping, or by clicking the button below:</p>
      </div> 
    
      <div data-role="header">
               <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">&#9776;</a>
        <h1>Chapar</h1>
         <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-right">Search</a>
    
    <!--  </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#contactPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Contacts</a>
        <a href="#myPanelFixed" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Dial Pad</a>
      </div>  -->
      <!--Buttons -->
        <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#contactPanel" data-icon="search">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#dialPanel" data-icon="search">Dial Pad</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="info">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Recent contacts-->
        <div id="myList">
         <ul  data-role="listview" data-input="#myFilter" data-inset="true">
          <li id="contact1"><a href="#">testContact</a></li>
         </ul>
         </div>
    
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Add entry</button>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        $("#myList").append('<ul  data-role="listview" data-input="#myFilter" data-inset="true"><li id="contact1"><a href="#">testContact</a></li></ul>');
    }
    </script>
    
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Page Footer</h1>
      </div> 
    </div> 
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: It seems Jquery Mobile... isn't it? you must specify it on your title, your description and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use clone() function to get the exact copy of the list and then append to the parent element.

```
function myFunction() {
    var clone = $("#myList ul:first").clone();
    $("#myList").append(clone);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/95/)

Comment: Hi Anoop, this way it uses same label as first element. Can you please tell me how I can add a new label from a variable? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After you add the `ul` element call the `listview()` function for the last appended ul.

Code Sample: `$("#myList > ul").last().listview();`

Please check the snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="panel" id="contactPanel"> 
            <a href="#pageone" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
        <form class="ui-filterable">
          <input id="myFilter" data-type="search">
        </form>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
          <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Albert</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cameron</a></li>
        </ul>
    
      </div> 
    
      <div data-role="panel" id="dialPanel" data-position-fixed="true"> 
       <a href="#pageone" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
        <h2>Dial a Number</h2>
        <p>You can close the panel by clicking outside the panel, pressing the Esc key, by swiping, or by clicking the button below:</p>
      </div> 
    
      <div data-role="header">
               <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">&#9776;</a>
        <h1>Chapar</h1>
         <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-right">Search</a>
    
    <!--  </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#contactPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Contacts</a>
        <a href="#myPanelFixed" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Dial Pad</a>
      </div>  -->
      <!--Buttons -->
        <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#contactPanel" data-icon="search">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#dialPanel" data-icon="search">Dial Pad</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="info">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Recent contacts-->
        <div id="myList">
         <ul  data-role="listview" data-input="#myFilter" data-inset="true">
          <li id="contact1"><a href="#">testContact</a></li>
         </ul>
         </div>
    
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Add entry</button>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        $("#myList").append('<ul  data-role="listview" data-input="#myFilter" data-inset="true"><li id="contact1"><a href="#">testContact</a></li></ul>')
        
       $("#myList > ul").last().listview();
    }
    </script>
    
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Page Footer</h1>
      </div> 
    </div> 
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Also if you want to add to existing ul you can use the `listview('refresh')` to refresh the listview.